# Element collection returning odd query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an many to many table which I am querying and want to return one column from it

Consider

```
Table 1

M to M (consisting of TABLE1_ID and TABLE2_ID)

Table2
```

I am in Table 2 entity and I want to return all the table 2 ids in the M to M table when I give it a table 1 id.

In my entity I have

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="M_TO_M_TABLE", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="TABLE1_ID"))
@Column(name="TABLE_2_ID")
private Set<Integer> tableTwoIds;
```

When I try and query this the JPA query that is produced is weird!

My query is

```
SELECT tab2 from Table2 tab2 where tab2.tableOneIds in (:idsPassedIn)
```

The error I get makes sense from the query that is generated. The error is

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Missing IN or OUT parameter at index:: 1
```

and the query is

```
select tab2.ID, tab2.NOTES
from TABLE_2 tab2, M_TO_M mToM 
where tab1.ID=mToM.TAB_1_ID and (. in (? , ?))
```

and we have a . after the and rather than mToM.TAB_2_ID

Has anyone any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: If you have a Many To Many relationship between tables Table1 and Table2, why wouldn't you just add a ManyToMany relationship to your entities?  You then would query "Select tab2 from Table1 tab1 join tab1.table2s tab2 where tab1.id in (:idsPassedIn)"

Comment: @Chris that is what I have just done to get past it. I thought this would be slightly less efficient though but it works at least

Comment: If you want to maintain the collection of IDs as a set of Integers instead of using the M:M object capabilities, it should work.  I notice that your query has "tab1.ID=mToM.TAB_1_ID" in it though, so I suspect you have multiple mappings to the 'M_TO_M_TABLE' table in your model, which would be wrong and cause you additional problems in the long run.  They might not be related to the . being added to the query, but you won't know unless you clean it up and post the full entities

Comment: Hi @Chris, it is a standard many to many table with two columns. I simplied my example so I may have simplified it too much.